# Returning a View with a List and a Single Variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'm feeling quite dumb right now. I have a view that is strongly typed to a list, but I also want to show a date when this list was last updated.

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Infotech.Coverpools.Portal.Tintaglia.CodeFirst.Models;

namespace Infotech.Coverpools.Portal.Tintaglia.Web.Controllers
{
    public class CustLedgerEntryController : Controller
    {
        private TintagliaContext db = new TintagliaContext();

        //
        // GET: /CustLedgerEntry/

        public ActionResult AccountHistory()
        {

            //UserProfile userprofile = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name));

            IEnumerable<CustLedgerEntry> ListCustLedgerEntries;
           {
                ListCustLedgerEntries = db.CustLedgerEntries.ToList();
            }

            return View(ListCustLedgerEntries);
        }
```

This is the code for the date I want to display (which I tried adding inside ListCustLedgerEntries, but I knew that was wrong).

```
        var datetoweb = db.CustLedgerEntries.FirstOrDefault(m => m.DatetoWebSales != null);
```

Here's my view

```
@model IEnumerable<Infotech.Coverpools.Portal.Tintaglia.CodeFirst.Models.CustLedgerEntry>

@using GridMvc.Html

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Account History";
    }


<h2>Account History</h2>
@*<link href="~/Content/Gridmvc.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>*@


@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Add(m => m.CustomerNo_).Titled("Account #").Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(m => m.PostingDate).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").SetWidth(100).Titled("Order Date").Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(m => m.DocumentType).Titled("Type").Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(m => m.DocumentNo_).Titled("Document #").Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(m => m.Description).Titled("Description").SetWidth(300).Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(m => m.ExternalDocumentNo_).Titled("Memo").SetWidth(300).Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(m => m.Amount).Format("{0:$#,###.00}").Titled("Amount").SetWidth(200).Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(m => m.RemainingAmount).Format("{0:$#,###.00}").SetWidth(100).Titled("Remaining Amount").Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(m => m.DueDate).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").Titled("Due Date").Filterable(true);
}).WithPaging(20).Sortable(true)

This is accurate as of //This is where I want the Date
```

Like I said, I know this should be easy. Any help in doing this and any tutorials better than I've found would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do it, One is to create a new view model which has 2 properties, Records and LastUpdatedDate

```
public classs AccountHistoryVm
{
  public IEnumerable<CustLedgerEntry> Records { set;get;}
  public DateTime? LastUpdatedDate { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your GET action, create an object of this, set the relevant properties and send to view

```
public ActionResult AccountHistory()
{
  var vm = new AccountHistoryVm();
  vm.Records= db.CustLedgerEntries.ToList();
  var d= db.CustLedgerEntries.FirstOrDefault(m => m.DatetoWebSales != null);
  id(d!=null)
  {
    vm.LastUpdateDate == d.DatetoWebSales; //Assuming DatetoWebSales is of DateTime type.
  }
  return View(vm);
}
```

Make sure your view is now strongly typed to this new view model

```
@model AccountHistoryVm
@if(Model.LastUpdatedDate!=null)
{
   <p>This is accurate as of @Model.LastUpdatedDate.Value.ToString() </p>
}
// Use Model.Records property to build the grid
```

Another option is to use ViewBag to pass the data.

Comment: I tried ViewBag, but I get the following result "This is accurate as of Infotech.Coverpools.Portal.Tintaglia.CodeFirst.Models.CustLedgerEntry" instead of the date. I added `ViewBag.datetoweb = db.CustLedgerEntries.FirstOrDefault(m => m.DatetoWebSales != null);` inside ListCustLegerEntries and `@ViewBag.datetoweb` in my view. I'll try the VM solution, but why am I getting this result?

Comment: Thank you. View Model worked. Still not sure why the ViewBag was returning the path instead of the data. I did `var datetoweb = db.CustLedgerEntries.FirstOrDefault(m => m.DatetoWebSales != null);
            vm.LastUpdatedDate = datetoweb.DatetoWebSales;` and `@Model.LastUpdateDate` instead of the id check for null.